# Stacking <dt> and <dt> in a multiple column, multiple row <dl>

Tags: css, html

Is it possible to get this look
[image: What the dl should look like]

from this code (using CSS?)

```
<dl>
<dt>Latitude</dt>
<dd>50.0</dd>
<dt>Longitude</dt>
<dd>100.0</dd>
<dt>h (metres)</dt>
<dd>0.000</dd>
<dt>Vφ (mm/y)</dt>
<dd>-6.4</dd>
<dt>Vλ (mm/y)</dt>
<dd>-15.3</dd>
<dt>Vh (mm/y)</dt>
<dd>-2.0</dd>
</dl>
```

Just to be clear, I don't care about the colors. It's the having the dt/dd pairs stacked with multiple columns and multiple rows that's important to me. I can get the look I want with a table, but it fails my accessibility criteria. I think a  is semantically closer to what I want... it's really a list of key/value pairs.

Here are the colors I'm using though:

```
dl {border: 1px solid #C8C8C8;}

dd {border: 1px solid #C8C8C8; background-color: #F0F0F0;}
```

Comment: That clearly falls into the category of tabular data and I can't imagine what accessibility criteria a properly marked up table (using `th` and `scope`) wouldn't meet. Care to elaborate on that?

Comment: You're right steveax, see my comment to cimmanon's post. It was my incorrect table structure that was causing the problem.

Comment: Hm... where did my image go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing inherently inaccessible about tables.  It's only when they're used for display rather than for expressing tabular data that it is a problem.  You *do* have tabular data, it just happens to have 2 columns.  Just because it is a 2-column 6-row table doesn't mean it has to look like one.

http://jsfiddle.net/hgWxT/

```
table, tbody {
    display: block;
}

tr {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
}

td, th {
    display: block;
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Latitude</th>
        <td>50.0</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Longitude</th>
        <td>100.0</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>h (metres)</th>
        <td>0.000</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Vf (mm/y)</th>
        <td>-6.4</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>V? (mm/y)</th>
        <td>-15.3</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Vh (mm/y)</th>
        <td>-2.0</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @cimmanon. This is indeed the best way to do it. My accessibility problems were caused by having a 3 column, 4 row table with the third row being another header row... which was confusing the screen readers. It seems so obvious now!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a basic solution, looks terrible, but with that structure you should be able to improve it after your requirements:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9vyWQ/1/)

CSS:

```
dl {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
}

dl dd {
    float: left;
    margin-left: -35px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width. 100px;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    border: 1px solid #777777;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
dl dt {
    float: left;
    width. 70px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Great use of CSS. I've got to give it to cimmanon though for setting me straight. +1 for sure

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's possible. Andy Clark is fond of using various lists and I've used dl's many times.

You just treat it like an ol/ul. Remove the margin/padding first.

Assign a class to the dt's, float them but you'll have to assign a different class to the second row. Sometimes not as if the width of the container of the DL is set, the dt's will wrap around but to really control the second row of dt (V (mm/y) and -6.4 ..that row) you can assign another class and style.

Answer (score -1):

Possible? Yes, but needlessly difficult.

Far, far, easier is to just wrap each `dt`/`dd` group of in an element, and style accordingly. Here's your example completed: http://cssdeck.com/labs/jsqdknho

Comment: That markup is invalid (divs can't wrap around dt/dd elements like that).

Comment: You can just change the elements if that's an issue to you. My solution is only an example, and it's only making a case for what's pragmatic and simple.

Comment: whatwg allows wrapping dt, dd in div (since Oct 31, 2016) see https://github.com/whatwg/html/commit/5454d702e0262749aba55576dda32c48e0e498f0

see also w3c discussion https://github.com/w3c/editing/issues/153